# Nodejs: child_process.exec get error when command return nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

When using child_process.exec in nodejs, it hit an error when the command return nothing. I do following:

```
const {exec} = require('child_process');

const cmd = `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep abc123.py`;
exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if(err) {
        console.error(`__get error: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(stdout);
    return;
})
```

Since 'abc123.py' is not running, it return nothing if run this command directly. But this code get this:

```
__get error:
```

I meet this error with **Node 8.10.0 and 10.16.0**. Is there anything I ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to exec nonexistent script, so your `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep abc123.py` return 1 as a exit code and write nothing to stderr. From [Nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) we know that the

> Any exit code other than 0 is considered to be an error.

So, your code works right.